# MYSQL How do I update a table only if a unique key pair of two columns does not exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, insert

I am setting up a voting program where I want to limit users to one vote up.  I have two tables: (a) subject table and (b) vote table.

```
**Subject_Table**              

SID   Subject   Total_Votes          
1     Cows      5     
2     Chickens  3     


**Vote_Table**

VID   Subject   User    Voteup           
1     Cows      John    1
```

Total votes equal votes from all users.  Voteup can only equal 1 if an subject is voted on.  I have made a unique value pair with Subject and User with the following statement without any problems:

```
ALTER TABLE Vote_Table ADD UNIQUE limitvote(Subject,User);
```

When a subject is voted on for the first time the following queries execute:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Vote_Table (Subject, User,Voteup) VALUES ('$Subject', '$User', '$Voteup') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE up=1";
$q = "UPDATE Subject_Table SET Total_Votes = $votes_up= //current votes plus 1;
```

Even if John votes twice the vote will always equal 1 in the Vote_Table due to ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE up=1.  But this is not so in the Subject_Table. Without a constraint, John could vote infinitely.  The constraint must be the subject-user pair.  Constraints cannot be only Subject or User since John can vote for other subjects and other users can vote for Cows.

How can I check Vote_Table to see if the unique Subject-User pair (Cows and John)) exists before I update Subject_Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incorporate it into the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE Subject_Table
   SET Total_Votes = Total_Votes + 1
 WHERE Subject = ...
   AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM Vote_Table
           WHERE Subject = ...
             AND User = ...
        )
;
```

That said, I'm not sure that you really need `Subject_Table` at all; you can create a view on the `Vote_Table` that will give you the same information, without having to create separate table. (See the [the Wikipedia article on Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).) That could look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Subject_View AS
SELECT Subject,
       COUNT(1) AS Total_Votes
  FROM Vote_Table
 GROUP
    BY Subject
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly.  I tried the WHERE NOT EXISTS in different forms before and couldn't get it to work.  It's all about syntax.  As for the view suggestion, I would create a view, but my tables are quite a bit more complicated than what I presented here.  Thanks for the thoughtful suggestion though!